# Calling objects with Python

Tags: python

I am learning OOP at the moment with python. I wrote the following code.

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy = Turtle()
timmy.shape("turtle")

my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.exitonclick()

print(my_screen.canvheight)
```

This works perfectly. My turtle shows up and everything is OK.

But when I change the line in the code below, It won't show up the turtle and instead it shows the error like the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ArunBohra\Documents\OOPS\main_file.py", line 16, in <module>
    timmy.shape("turtle")

  File "C:\Python 39\lib\turtle.py", line 2779, in shape
    self._update()
  
  File "C:\Python 39\lib\turtle.py", line 2661, in _update
    self._update_data()

  File "C:\Python 39\lib\turtle.py", line 2647, in _update_data
    self.screen._incrementudc()

  File "C:\Python 39\lib\turtle.py", line 1293, in _incrementudc
    raise Terminator
    turtle.Terminator
```

Here's the code that gives the errors:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

timmy = Turtle()

my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.exitonclick()
timmy.shape("turtle")

print(my_screen.canvheight)
```

Comment: What is the error? Please include the _full traceback_, not just the first line (that doesn't give much useful info)

Comment: It's the last line that has the error message

Comment: It has to do with the order of the lines that are executed.

Comment: I have included the full traceback

Comment: @ArunBohra That still isn't the full traceback. You're still missing the last line, which lists the actual error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the turtle module, if the screen is not running it will raise an error.

**Code snippet from the turtle module:**

```
    if not TurtleScreen._RUNNING:
        TurtleScreen._RUNNING = True
        raise Terminator
```

You can ignore the error by simply using a try-except statement

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
    
timmy = Turtle()
    
my_screen = Screen()
my_screen.exitonclick()
    
try:
   timmy.shape("turtle")
except Terminator:
   pass
    
print(my_screen.canvheight)
```

Comment: Better still, `except Terminator:` rather than that bare `except:` clause which should be discouraged, since it evaluates to `except BaseException:` which will catch things like `SystemExit` and `KeyboardInterrupt` exceptions which make it difficult to interrupt a running program.